# GeneralSecurityException: Invalid signature. (RewardedAdsVerifier - SSV)

Tags: server, admob, signature

I clearly followed this insctructions: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video-ssv#ssv_callback_parameters

My server - spring v2.1.10 (maven), 
To implement server verification, I used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.crypto.tink</groupId>
        <artifactId>apps-rewardedads</artifactId>
        <version>HEAD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.crypto.tink</groupId>
    <artifactId>tink</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

RewardedAdsVerifier.class > https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/apps/rewardedads/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/apps/rewardedads/RewardedAdsVerifier.java

CryptoTinkLibrary > https://github.com/google/tink

Filling the server on the hosting, I started to configure and check on the site admob.com , but got an HTTP-error 404, on the server i got the following exception:

```
java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Invalid signature
    at com.google.crypto.tink.subtle.EcdsaVerifyJce.verify(EcdsaVerifyJce.java:68)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.rewardedads.RewardedAdsVerifier.verify(RewardedAdsVerifier.java:166)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.apps.rewardedads.RewardedAdsVerifier.verify(RewardedAdsVerifier.java:151)
    at com.appsbybananni.luckybitcoin.services.rewards.RewardService.getLowReward(RewardService.java:44)
    at com.appsbybananni.luckybitcoin.controllers.user.ControllerUser.getLowRewards(ControllerUser.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Signature and key_id are valid and provided by admob.
The second day I can't find a solution to this problem. Please help me.

My Controller:

```
        @RequestMapping(path = "/get_low_reward")
    public void getLowRewards(@RequestParam(required = false) String user_id,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String ad_network,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String ad_unit,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String timestamp,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String transaction_id,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String signature,
                              @RequestParam(required = false) String key_id)  {
        String rewardUrl = "https://my.server.ru/path?"
                + "ad_network=" + ad_network
                + "&ad_unit=" + ad_unit
                + "&user_id=" + user_id
                + "&timestamp=" + timestamp
                + "&transaction_id" + transaction_id
                + "&signature=" + signature
                + "&key_id=" + key_id;
        RewardService rewardService = new RewardService(userRepository, generalSettingsRepository);
        rewardService.getLowReward(rewardUrl, user_id);
```

Then this code is executed:

```
  try {
                RewardedAdsVerifier verifier = new RewardedAdsVerifier.Builder()
                        .fetchVerifyingPublicKeysWith(RewardedAdsVerifier.KEYS_DOWNLOADER_INSTANCE_PROD)
                        .build();
                verifier.verify(rewardUrl);
                .....
```

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason. I know the post is old, but someone might need it.

Firstly, make sure you are encoding each parameter with

```
URLEncoder.encode(param, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Secondly, Make sure you are using correct configuration.

1. [Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-ssv#ssv_callback_parameters)
2. [iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video-ssv#ssv_callback_parameters)
3. [Unity](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-video-ssv#ssv_callback_parameters)

There are 3 different setup Requirements for different platforms, the platform on AdMob app should match the setup you are using.